# How to prevent deadlock in try/except/finally while interrupting the main method from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, concurrency

I saw this deadlock in an application which resulted in it getting stuck. The application has a main thread as well as a thread that processes some work in the background.

A connection error occurred to a service both threads use at the same time. The main thread catches exceptions with `except Exception`, the background thread catches errors and interrupts the main application whenever they occur. A deadlock occurs in the python logging module while acquiring the lock to serialize writes to standard output. Below is a reproduction of the deadlock (without logging modulo, but mimics its behavior)

```
import thread
from threading import Thread, RLock

lock = RLock()

def log(msg):
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        print msg
    finally:
        lock.release()

def run():
    thread.interrupt_main()

Thread(target=run).start()
try:
    1 / 0
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    log('keyboardinterrupt')
except Exception, e:
    log('Exception')
    raise
finally:
    log('finally')
```

Run it in a loop and the deadlock will eventually occur.

```
while true; do python deadlock.py; done
```

`finally` and `except` execution kick off together from what I see in the docs, both ask for the lock, one of them wins, then the application is interrupted by the thread, and if that happens before the owning thread releases the lock, the other thread is left waiting for the lock and the application gets stuck doing nothing.

A fix would be to acquire the lock in a try and release it in a finally, but it is acquired outside the try in python [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L757). Which I think makes sense since it is supposed to block until it gets the lock or fail.

I can do that in my application with something like:

```
try:
    log.info('msg')
finally:
    for handler in log.handlers:  # (and its parents' handlers)
        try:
            handler.lock.release()
        except:  # ignore if it was not acquired
            pass
```

But that does not look right, and I am wondering if there is a better solution here?

I thought about not interrupting the main thread when an error occurs in the thread and instead use an error queue (similar to go), and check the queue in the main app loop and raise an error from there, but that can add delay to surfacing these errors.

Comment: I'm currently working on something with a similar setup as you with the two separate processes, dunno if it's what you're after though (the processing part was too heavy to run as a thread). If an error happens in the main part, it'll simply get caught and written to a file. However, if one happens in a background thread, the text is sent back via `Queue`, and if the main thread detects that it's an exception that has been sent back, it'll write that text to the file and stop the script.

Comment: yeah, that's one solution I am considering and listed it in the question. Seems like a good solution, but adds a bit of delay.

Comment: Oh just noticed that part haha, kinda skim read it since I wasn't properly answering :P  Does the delay matter that much though?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find this dilemma is not resolvable in Python.  This is exactly the case that caused the .NET locks to be reworked to include Boolean arguments passed by reference and guaranteed to be atomically set when/if the lock is acquired.  The C# using/lock statements (similar to Context Managers) were then reworked to utilize this pattern.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498.aspx